# Passing lambda as parameter to Method that will query a ResourceSet

Tags: c#, lambda

I have to filter a `ResourceSet` by some string pattern in each `Key`. My function must receive as parameter a **lambda expression** for this purpose. I'm not experienced with **lambda**, so I have no idea how to query a  each **DictionaryEntry** in the **ResourceSet**.

Here's my current method, but looks ugly and old:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> FindStrings(string resourceName, params string[] pattern)
{
    OpenResource(resourceName);

    ResourceSet resourceSet = _currentResourseManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
    {
        string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();

        foreach (string p in pattern)
        {
            if (resourceKey.StartsWith(p))
            {
                string resource = entry.Value.ToString();
                result.Add(resourceKey, resource);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

How my Func parameter will look? How the lambda will look?

Comment: Well, based on your problem description, it sounds like you won't actually be changing much of your method - just the "if resourceKey.startsWith"; you need to provide a Func that takes a string, and returns a boolean (passes filter). Here's the documentation for Func if it helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx Anything missing, or did I misinterpret your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass a *predicate* which is a function accepting a string and returning a boolean value indicating whether the input string matches some condition.

Here's how your implementation can look like:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> FindStrings(string resourceName, Func<string, boolean> keySelector)
{
    OpenResource(resourceName);

    ResourceSet resourceSet = _currentResourseManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
    {
        string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();

        if (keySelector(resourceKey))
        {
            string resource = entry.Value.ToString();
            result.Add(resourceKey, resource);
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

And here's how you can call the method using lambda expression:

```
var patterns = new string[] { "test1", "test2" };
var results = FindString("Resource1", key => patterns.Any(p => key.StartsWith(p)));
```

More on delegates: [Delegates (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
More on lambda expressions: [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).

Hope this helps.